# Handling multiple events but fire handler only for one event

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-deployment, jquery-events

How to fire event handler only once for multiple event types?

```
$("p").on("click touchend", function(e) {
    console.log( "<p> was clicked" );
});
```

This handler is called on some devices twice - firstly for "touchend" event (or "touchstart" for example - it doesn't matter in this case), and then this handler is automatically triggered again for "click" event.

It works like `"click" && "touchend"` but I want it to act like `"click" || "touchend"`.
Is there a simple way to **prevent calling the handler for "click" when "touch(start/end)" was triggered** and vice versa? The only solution I figured out is to unbind "click" event if `e.type` was "touchend".

I found information that `.on("click touchend")` should work only for one event form the collection, but I've checked that it's fired twice, at least on few mobile devices, so you have a better solution for this case?

Comment: try adding `return false;` or `e.preventDefault()`. Might be a bubbling problem

Comment: is this code inside an iterator or a loop?

Answer (score 1):

I was not that sure to answer, but you can determine the `event` right

```
var clickEvent = ((document.ontouchend===null)?'click':'touchend');
$("p").on(clickEvent, function(e) {
   console.log( "<p> was "+e );
});
```

Comment: It can be an option, I was using this but everything gets more complicated with msPointerEvents support on Windows Phone

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're loading your jQuery. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("p").on("click touchend", function(e) {
         if(e.type == "click"){
              console.log( "<p> was clicked" );
         } else if(e.type == "touchend"){
              console.log( "<p> was touched" );
         }
    });

});
```

Comment: if they are iterating and binding the event, then it will fire more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Since these events always come in order, first touchend in touch devices, then click, you can either check for if it's touch device and then bind only to touchend, and if it's not bind click.

However binding to only touch end is a problem when the user starts touching somewhere else, drags and ends up on your button (think scrolling).

My guess is you are using this for faster clicks, without the 300ms delay in mobiles, try this library [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) which will listen to both touch start and touch end and will call the click handler immediately etc, and then you can bind to only click on all devices.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)

> Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the
>   event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").on("click touchend", function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    console.log( "<p> was clicked" );
});
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7w0s43f7/

Comment: But that's the same handler, that's the events that are differents. If i understand it, e.g using `click mouseup`, same handler is called twice: http://jsfiddle.net/7w0s43f7/1/